# PL/SQL update rate using having count

Tags: plsql, count, having

Hi am newbie at pl/sql

I need to update rate_per_hour for all projects having less than 5 employee to 500

here is the code what i wrote, but it updates all employee

```
set serveroutput on

declare
  cursor rate_cur is
  select * from project
  for update of rate_per_hour;
begin
  for rate_rec IN rate_cur
  loop
    update project
    set rate_per_hour=500
    where current of rate_cur;
  end loop;

end;
```

Here is my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE employee(
empid number(5),
empname varchar(20),
address varchar(20),
no_of_dependents number(5),
deptno number(5),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(empid),
CONSTRAINT EMPLOYEE_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(deptno) REFERENCES department(deptno));

CREATE TABLE project(
projectno number(5),
location varchar(20),
incharge number(5),
rate_per_hour number(5),
CONSTRAINT PROJECT_PKEY PRIMARY KEY(projectno),
CONSTRAINT PROJECT_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(incharge) REFERENCES employee(empid));

CREATE TABLE assignment(
empid number(5),
projectid number(5),
hours number(5),
CONSTRAINT ASSIGNMENT_FKEY FOREIGN KEY(empid) REFERENCES employee(empid),
CONSTRAINT ASSIGNEMNT_FKEY2 FOREIGN KEY(projectid) REFERENCES project(projectno));




  Please suggest a solution
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found help on another forums! Here is the code

```
update project
set    rate_per_hour = 500
where  projectno IN 
    (select projectid
     from assignment
     group by projectid
     having count(distinct empid) <5);
```

Answer (score 1):

It updates all because you are selecting all projects without limit. You can change the cursor to something like:

```
declare
  cursor RATE_CUR is
    select     P.PROJECTNO, count(*) as EMP_CNT
    from       PROJECT P
               join ASSIGNMENT A
                 on A.PROJECTID = P.PROJECTNO
    group by   PROJECTNO
    having     count(*) < 5;
begin
  for RATE_REC in RATE_CUR loop
    update PROJECT
    set    RATE_PER_HOUR = 500
    where  PROJECTNO = RATE_REC.PROJECTNO;
  end loop;
end;
```

Comment: FOR UPDATE of this query expression is not allowed. even if delete for update and change line |where projectno=rate_cur.projectno| to |where prokectno=rate_rec.projectno|    "RATE_CUR"."PROJEC_TNO": invalid identifier

Comment: I edited it to fix those spelling mistakes. Your solution from another forum is better as it's just pure SQL, I was aiming to fix your PL/SQL.